# returning value from ajax, back to the JS function that it

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

here is the problem.

i have `HTML Form` and it has a button `submit` with an `onclick=validationFunction()`. When i click this button, values from form goes to this function.

Now, in this function, the values of the form are che`enter code here`cked if`enter code here` they are correct or not. In addition, it has 1 `input Field` who has to be checked for validation, and also checked again from database to see it that value exists there. This part is done via `ajax`. Below the ajax call, there is a return value`(boolen)` for the function `validationFucntion()`.

Now, what i want. i want either of the two things.

1) ajax should return true or false within its `success`

2) or ajax should send the value just below where the ajax call ends. By now, i m failing big times to do either of the things.

Here is a sample pseudo code.

```
    function validationFunction()
{

     validations checks in progress
     $.ajax({
     url:'checkIfNumberExists.php',
     data : {
             'number : num //this num is coming from above
            },

     method:'GET',
     success: function(data)
            {
                console.log("Return Value = "+this.toReturn);
                if(  (this.toReturn) > 0 )
                {
                     either return validationFunction from here or set a flag.
                }
                else
                {
                     either return validationFunction from here or set a flag.
                }

     });
}
```

checkIfNumberExists.php

```
<?php

$num = $_GET['number'];
$toReturn = 0 ;

$queryCheckNo = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `number_from_table`="'.$num.'" ');


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryCheckNo)){
    $toReturn++;
}
echo ($toReturn);
?>
```

Comment: $.ajax is asynchronous, and function call  is synchronous

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Comment: tried these links, but still the problem remains the same, maybe i have to change the design.

Comment: to get what you want , you can't use: onsubmit="return validationFunction()" cause your function is asynchronous.
you need to design your own bloking/unblocking ui for the form while the ajax processes..

Answer (score 0):

try this plug in

```
<script>
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
       $("#tempForm").ajaxForm({
       url:'../calling action or servlet',
       type:'post',
       beforeSend:function()
       {
         alert("perform action before making the ajax call like showing spinner image");
       },
       success:function(e){
        alert("data is"+e);
            alert("now do whatever you want with the data");
       }
       });
    });
</script>
```

and keep this inside your form

```
<form id="tempForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="" id="" />
</form>
```

and you can find the plug in [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#download)

Comment: :( not fulfilling the task